# What are the redirect parameters for Google and Yandex?

Tags: google-search, yandex-search

I did a Google search and clicked on one of the results. Google redirected to a different URL when I clicked on the result. Yandex has a similar redirection.

For Google:

```
http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trt.net.tr%2F&ei=EcJCUtScO8bCswau34Fg&usg=AFQjCNFMkf5e1tT79uYuCldO5mP6k_bWQQ&bvm=bv.53077864,d.Yms
```

For Yandex:

```
http://www.yandex.com.tr/clck/jsredir?from=www.yandex.com.tr%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=trt&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW9l18DHb9MflkVwq5B3fjRC_m3WpZIsom1YcC5c_CBOinjm_BZZpbEbfcxgEVVjIlEE5GY-eupPAVFV2pSVTgQWHn_086xYnCTb4s4OgE1ghGVvyo-HqjsD9MQuWXpGQdPsiPauuPQCJFn04b_dh9xg98tBoxdtmi2vtXoGmAyTLc&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbGg5My0yemVSVG9QRXdJVzBIUGtDb1k3TVJIdDBLNjJyeEl iaHBZaVQtZlRpNTYtN3JwWk9SSE9zd3A5OFdERDI3bWNCOUFYUlZh&b64e=2&sign=b36f0ae93847e3c136d7dd548ec584da&keyno=0&l10n=tr
```

I found a [site](http://dc-storm.com/en-uk/news-events/news/google-announces-default-ssl-searches/) related to it. I wonder what are parameters for the URLs. Does anyone know of a source site for it?

Comment: I made a question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/151676/2379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection links are done as a way for Google and Yandex to correlate what search terms result in more clicks to certain websites for certain localities/demographics as well as camouflage the referrer. These parameters are likely proprietary to each of the search engines and not a part of public information, since it would help people 'game' the search ranking/keyword ranking system.

[This page](http://www.t75.org/2012/06/deconstructing-googles-url-search-parameters/) has some speculation and deconstruction of the parameters for Google, but most of it is a mystery and is ultimately for providing Google with more data for their Analytics.

Comment: Bad answer, the page linked is exactly the same as this page, both having **no answers**.