# Is there any way to rebuild Yandex redirect URL?

Tags: yandex-search

I've gotten some visits to pages that are supposed to be completely hidden from everyone via Yandex and I'd love to find out 1) what search term led them to it and 2) the referring page on my site.  The problem is that in spite spending over an hour trying to utilize the vars in the URL, I can't get a legitimate search page on Yandex.  Here's the URL in question:

```
http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1271.RJS9ZfLhVdj6nXam87qy4e0e-DG9BQd_KlyA1gFVBu1uuZOuUSRTgOEasX71Cupm.fe839c38b17c539463c0b2f7d01d86940f4b3320&uuid=&state=_BLhILn4SxNIvvL0W45KSic66uCIg23qh8iRG98qeIXmeppkgUc0YL_nDC5hqtEQ6WayFoZKRZE&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXUFJiWDhna1NqZnBmd1YzNG43VS13RUpmdUZXdnBLOHdkMFlqUzVDamF1OVBVb2xkMmtvMUxXWUxJM1hSVW5hS2x5R1R6LVpCcGVXZFZZNkprR0JOSUVPc3d0ZnBVOXpDV295ckZDdFpqS3l4WkZSOFF3c0RmVTN2ZkhIYWIwT0JzNVQyWko5ME9vMw&b64e=2&sign=08505d8afebc7cb1b4568d3e92c11ecb&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQXbYQp9t5VF6sf_IfF4r6pdt0ojCe4cFQNegojWnJn8UToJJyLyR96RrC_bl9mqJxfCjbo3nl3EPqUjNd2ADc0Zxar8tKC1hQd4R3WTMI1AD3dVkg_IhwheNgkWXjuLnig&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kp5uQozpMtKCXdCnh-_wii4V8gT36dWFhYdLgT8HVc5IPL1yluhUPYHlzmn9nr8Aaa3y8eC13fJRd5RgTTAPeGmg&l10n=ru&cts=1481853806438&mc=4.32492874929
```

I took the code after the redir URL and tried adding the var and value etext on to the Yandex search URL but nothing has worked so far.

I've already downloaded the entire site via wget while using both a browser and Yandex search UA(it's how my site distinguishes bots to hide logins and human-specific content).  Doing a search through all the downloaded content, I was unable to find any instance of the URLs in question.

---

I had found the link you posted concerning "What are the redirect parapeters for Google and Yandex" already but both that link and the links included in it really only deal with Google and not at all with Yandex.

By #2, I mean that I'd love to see the Yandex search page so I could find out what referring page on my site led the spider to the off-limits and supposedly hidden pages.

the "text" var is completely empty in the yandex redir link and all the important stuff seems to be held instead in the "etext" var which I'm both unable to figure out how to use in the Yandex URL and even figure out what it's for. The only search string related topics I can find are in Russian and translation did not treat them kindly.

Comment: While not off-topic here, you'll probably get better expertise on this issue at [webmasters.se].

Comment: The URL you've posted is presumably the referring URL ("HTTP Referer") in your logs. What do you mean by "2) the referring page on my site"? If by "referring page" you mean the page on your site that lead to the discovery of this "hidden page" then I very much doubt that information is stored in the referring URL.

Comment: Related (possibly even duplicate) question: [What are the redirect parameters for Google and Yandex?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50038/what-are-the-redirect-parameters-for-google-and-yandex)

Comment: Cross site post: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102109/is-there-any-way-to-rebuild-yandex-redirect-url

Comment: Please use the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page to merge your two accounts.  That way you can comment.